# Create android test project in intellij idea 13 community edition

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm using new intellij idea 13 (community edition) and have some problems creating tests for my android project. There are no modules with test option and as I can remember this kind of module was part of older intellij(or maybe not community edition). Is there any simple way to create this kind of project ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on how to do it:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/testing-android-applications.html

make sure you add the original android module as a dependency for the test module.

Comment: I have a Gradle android project and that does not seam to be an option. I am using IntelliJ 13.1.3 ultimate.